# Tapestry 5.3 how to retrieve textfield value with a button but without submit the form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, jakarta-ee, tapestry

My issue is that I would like to retrieve a textfield value without submit my form.

I think the solution should be a mixin event but I am not good enough to perform this.

Here an example about what I try to do :

```
<form t:type="form" t:id="myForm">
<t:errors banner="msgError" />
<t:zone t:id="zone1" id="zone1" elementName="zone1">
    ... some fields ...
</t:zone>
<t:zone t:id="zone2" id="zone2" elementName="zone2">
    <t:label for="select">Société :</t:label>
    <t:select t:id="select" model="selectModel" encoder="myEncoder"
        value="selectedvalue" blankOption="never" />
    <t:if test="isAdd">
        <input t:type="TextField" t:id="valueField" t:validate="required"
            size="45" t:value="value" />
        <t:actionlink t:id="addNew" context="value">${message:add }</t:actionlink>
        <p:else>
            <t:actionlink t:id="add">${message:add } ?</t:actionlink>
        </p:else>
    </t:if>
</t:zone>
<t:zone t:id="zone2" id="zone2" elementName="zone2">
    ...some other fields;
</t:zone>
<input type="submit" value="${message:valid }" />
```

So, I would like a button or link for add dynamically an option for my select. The select is feeded by my DAO. The goal is to get a link that change the statut of "isAdd" and then, display a textField with a button for adding a new value in my database and refresh the select component. 
I am sorry for my english, I hope you can understand the meaning...

Note that I have no constraint and can use javascript/ajax.

The answer can help me in many usages so I would be really happy if you can.

Tell me if you need more informations, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [observe](http://t5stitch-lazan.rhcloud.com/observedemo) mixin from tapestry-stitch. Attach the mixin to the 'click' event on the button button and set the `fields` parameter to the clientId of the textfield. Note, you'll probably use the [Any](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Any.html) component to render your button. Since, I'm guessing, you don't need the textfield value in the submit of the form, you could use a normal html input instead of a TextField.

TML

```
<t:zone t:id="myZone">
   <t:select ... />
</t:zone>
...
<input type="text" id="valueField" />
<t:any
    t:id="addNew" 
    element="button" 
    t:mixins="stitch/observe" 
    event="click" 
    zone="myZone" 
    fields="['valueField']"
>${message:add}</t:any>
```

Java

```
@Inject
private Zone myZone;

Object onClickFromAddNew(String value) {
    // do stuff
    return myZone.getBody();
}
```

Comment: I validated your answer because it works well but I couldn't do it with your ['valueField'] syntax... Thrown me a coercion issue. So I used a get method that returns a String[] with only one element (the input ID)
Why does your syntax can't be used by my Tapestry ? I copied exactly what you put ( fields="['valueField']" ), I shouldn't have ?
Thanks, twice that you help me much !

Comment: It looks like tapestry's [TypeCoercer](http://tapestry.apache.org/typecoercer-service.html) is having troubles coercing between Object[] and String[]. One solution is to declare ```List<String>``` in the mixin instead of ```String[]```. Another solution is to [contribute](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-configuration.html) a [CoercionTuple](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ioc/services/CoercionTuple.html) for Object[] --> String[] to the [TypeCoercer](http://tapestry.apache.org/current/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/ioc/services/TypeCoercer.html)